# Чому питання-дублікати про активні дієприкметники теперішнього часу, що закінчуються на -ачий, -ячий, учий, -ючий, не були відмічені як дублікати?

Tags: discussion

Якщо я правильно розумію, то це найперше питання, котре було поставлене по темі:
["Межі застосування дієприкметників"](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%96-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2/1294#1294)

Проте, я знайшов **десяток** питань-дублікатів про активні дієприкметники теперішнього часу, що закінчуються на -ачий, -ячий, учий, -ючий, котрі були поставлені вже після [оригінального](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/1262/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%96-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2/1294#1294)(і я ще не впевнений, що знайшов усі):
[**1**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%83-%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83/5664#5664), [**2**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3270/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%96%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9/3274#3274), [**3**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%83-%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83/5667#5667), [**4**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3273/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%96%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%B6-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8?noredirect=1&lq=1), [**5**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3477/%D0%AF%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9?rq=1), [**6**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%87-%D1%87%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9?rq=1), [**7**](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3234/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B9?rq=1)

Чому ці питання не були відмічені як дублікати і [нові питання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/%D0%A7%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%94%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D1%83-%D1%86%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D1%83/5664#5664) по темі досі отримують відповіді і не відмічаються як дублікати також?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема цілком типова, серед нас є прихильники як закриття, так і залишення окремих запитань. Аргументація також зрозуміла:

- з одного боку, мати одне [*канонічне запитання*](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/1262/8) по кожній темі дозволить зосередити увагу читачів і авторів відповідей;
- з іншого боку, є така штука, як *searchability*. Коли людина (що не є нашим користувачем) заходить в пошуковик і шукає неправильно. Тобто, замість пошуку за ключовим словом «активні дієприкметники» шукає конкретний приклад як-то *«нападаючий»*. **І не знаходить нашого канонічного допису!** Тому що в ньому слова *«нападаючий»* нема, але натомість є *«оточуючий»*. А весь словник слів-прикладів у канонічне запитання не вміститься.

Тому і рішення вбачається цілком очевидним:

1. робимо *канонічне* запитання (або дописуємо наявне до стану канонічності);
2. бажано — двомовне, з англійською версією;
3. чекаємо, поки воно упевнено отримуватиме тисячі переглядів;
4. маємо моральне право закривати наступні, *специфічні* запитання — але, знов-таки, з обмеженнями:

   - якщо автор *специфічного* запитання не доклав зусиль до пошуку, то можна голосувати за закриття з посиланням на *канонічне*;
   - а якщо він написав «я бачив *канонічне* запитання, але воно не дало мені відповіді з таких-то причин» — то тоді не закривати, а лишати як є.

Comment: Але ж закриття питання як дубліката(або взагалі з будь-якої причини) **не видаляє** його на сайтах Stack Exchange, воно все одно залишається існувати, просто на нього вже не можна відповідати. Відповідно *searchability* **абсолютно ніяк** не страждає. Це буде відбуватися, якщо автори будуть видаляти питання після їхнього закриття, чого, зазвичай, ніхто не робить в таких ситуаціях.

Comment: Слушно, я так само вважаю, але треба бути готовим до того, що серед нас є прихильники протилежної думки. Але головна проблема, на мою думку, — не плюралізм поглядів, а мала кількість таких *канонічних* дописів і невелика кількість бажаючих (← активний дієприкметник:) вкладати сили у розбудову цих канонічних дописів.